# D'Alembertian symbol $\Box$

Tags: notation, calculus, differential-equations

The D'Alembertian is a generalization of the Laplacian operator to a space of arbitrary dimension and metric.

Where does the D'Alembertian symbol $\Box$ come from?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator) it has to do with 4-dimensional spaces, but the authors don't cite sources and I don't see why the relation.

Comment: The laplacian in 3d is sometimes denoted by a triangle (sitting on its base: see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).  In 4d, it becomes a square.

Comment: Why don't a diamond then? Maybe if you know where was this notation used for the first time I can find the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol seems due to **Poincaré** ([1901](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?32.0818.03), [p. 456](//archive.org/stream/lectricitetopti00poingoog#page/n481)):

> For brevity we will introduce the following symbol, by setting,
>   $$
> \Delta\mathrm U -\mathrm K_0\frac{d^2\mathrm U}{dt^2}=\Box\mathrm U
> $$

Here $\mathrm K_0=1\,/\,c^2$ ([p. 336](//archive.org/stream/lectricitetopti00poingoog#page/n361)). It didn’t immediately catch on: it appears without comment in Poincaré’s ([1906](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?37.0886.01), [p. 132](//www.archive.org/stream/rendicontidelci09palegoog#page/n156)) (cited by Wikipedia), but not in the book where **Lorentz** named it ([1909](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?40.0922.01), [p. 17](//archive.org/stream/electronstheory00lorerich#page/17)):

> the operation $\Delta-\frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$ may be given the name of the *Dalembertian* (...) in commemoration of the fact that the mathematician d’Alembert was the first to solve a partial differential equation (...) which contains this operation, or rather the operation $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac1{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$

In ([1910](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?41.0143.01), [p. 175](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=uva.x001677364&num=175)) Lewis (of photon fame) was still suggesting the notation
$$
\diamondsuit^2=
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_2^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_3^2} +
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_4^2}\qquad(x_4=ict),
$$
but Sommerfeld ([1910](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?41.0759.01), [p. 661](//babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?u=1&id=umn.31951d003144375&num=661)) and von Laue ([1911](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?42.0718.04), [p. 71](//archive.org/stream/dasrelativittsp00lauegoog#page/n85)) chose again $\Box$ (pronounced “Delta”).

**Note:** Sommerfeld (ibid.) says the symbol was already introduced by **Cauchy**. This is repeated by Silberstein ([1912](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?44.0778.01), [p. 805](//archive.org/stream/londonedinburg6231912lond#page/805); [1914](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?45.1150.07), [p. 113](//archive.org/stream/theoryofrelativi00silbrich#page/113)), Bateman ([1915](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?45.1324.05), [p. 6](//archive.org/stream/mathematicalanal00baterich#page/6)) and Pauli ([1921](//emis.de/cgi-bin/JFM-item?48.0977.01), [p. 607](//archive.org/stream/encyklomath205encyrich#page/n618)), but neither gives a citation. (Perhaps they mean [this](//archive.org/stream/exercicesdanaly02caucrich#page/n349)?)